# Format Time in a DateTimePicker as Region settings change

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker, regional-settings

I want to format the time DateTimePicker to 24 hours.

I used the following code and the time is actually changed to 24 hours.
The problem now is that the date format takes an undesirable shape when using an Arabic Region for the device or an English region.
I want the direction of the date to not change no matter how different the region of the device.

I want the direction of the date to be Hours, Minutes and AM/PM as in the picture, regardless of the time zone.

[image]

My code:

```
If Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName.Contains("arab".ToLower)  Then
    ROSYUPDATE_F.DateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    ROSYUPDATE_F.DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt" 
Else

    ROSYUPDATE_F.DateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    ROSYUPDATE_F.DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " tt mm:HH"
End If
```

Animation that changes the time from the desired format

[image]

Comment: Your time format makes no sense. Why would you use "HH", which is specifically for 24-hour time, along with "tt", which is specifically for 12-hour time? The whole point of displaying "AM" or "PM" is so that you know which part of the day a 12-hour time relates to but that is meaningless for a 12-hour time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the Regional settings, `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` or (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) are not *automatically* updated.
You can call [CultureInfo.ClearCachedData()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata) to reset the internal `CultureData` stored settings and reload *fresh* values.

To update your UI when User settings change, you can handle notifications that the System sends when these settings have changed.

A simple way to acknowledge these notifications is to handle the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message that is sent to all top-level Windows when *something* in the System settings has changed.
These notifications are somewhat *generic* (read the Docs about it), but you can have a general idea of what has changed inspecting the `WParam` and `LParam` values.

Override `WndProc` in your Form to handle `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` messages.
When you get one, verify which settings have changed and act on this information.

In this case, when Regional (User) settings change, `WParam` is set to `0` and `LParam` points to a string that reads `"intl"`.
Then, if the Language is RTL (or a non-specific Arabic language - what you get with `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("AR")`), set your Custom Format, otherwise you can set the default `ShortTimePattern`, or whatever.
(Assume the DateTimePicker control is named `DateTimePicker1`)

```
Private Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE As Integer = &H1A

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WM_SETTINGCHANGE
            Dim lparmSetting = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(m.LParam)
            If m.WParam.ToInt32() = 0 AndAlso lparmSetting.Equals("intl") Then
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()
                DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = If(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft,
                    "tt mm:hh", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern)
            End If
    End Select
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

---

Secondary:
Since your Custom format is *not exactly standard*, you may have a different behavior when the Form is first loaded, depending on the current Regional Settings of the machine where your app is run.
You can send a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to *yourself*, with `WParam` and `LParam` set as described, so you update and format your DateTimePicker *automatically* on startup.

In `Form.Load` (or `OnLoad()` or `OnShown()` or `OnHandleCreated()`), your can add:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("intl"))
End Sub
```

SendMessage declaration:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, uMsg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```